# VUEX - can´t access to an object returned by GETTER

Tags: javascript, object, vuex, vuejs3, getter

I need to access to a property of the object "articulos" on the view "Pop.vue".
This object is return by a **Getter**.

I can see the whole object "articulos" on the view, like this:

```js
{"id": "1", "nombre": "Bolso1", "categoria": "Bolso"}
```

but I can´t display just one of the properties. I have tried with

```
{{obtenerArticuloPorId.nombre}}
```

Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nombre')

This is my code (I have commented code in relation with this in order to make reading easier):

**index.js** (Store)

```js
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export default createStore({
   state: {
      categoriaArticulos: [
        "lamina", "bolso"
      ],
    articulos: [
        {id: '0', nombre: "Imagen1", categoria: "lamina"},
        {id: '1', nombre: "Imagen2", categoria: "lamina"},
        {id: '2', nombre: "Bolso1", categoria: "bolso"},
        {id: '3', nombre: "Bolso2", categoria: "bolso"}
      ],
      id: ''
   },
   mutations: {
      obtenerId(state, payload){
        state.id=payload
      }
   },
   actions:{
      obtenerId({commit}, id){
         commit('obtenerId', id)
      }
   },
   getters: {
      obtenerArticulosPorCategoria: (state) => (id) => {
          return state.articulos.filter(art=> art.categoria==id)
      },
      obtenerArticuloPorId(state){
          const articulo=state.articulos.find(art=> art.id===state.id)
          return articulo
      }
   }
```

**Pop.vue**

```html
<template>
   <div class="popup">
       {{obtenerArticuloPorId}}
   </div>
</template>

<script>
    import {mapActions, mapGetters} from 'vuex'

    export default {

    methods:{
       ...mapActions(['obtenerId'])
    },
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters(['obtenerArticuloPorId'])
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have just edited the code. In fact I was trying with Array.prototype.find( ), the problem was not with Array.prototype.filter(). Summarizing, it is not working with find( )

Comment: `Array.prototype.find()` returns `undefined` if nothing matches. Since your `id` state property is an empty string and none of the `articulos` elements have an empty string `id`, you get no matches

Comment: As I explain on the code, obtenerArticuloPorId (Getter) returns: {"id": "1", "nombre": "Bolso1", "categoria": "Bolso"} I can see the whole object displays on the view and the console. So its returns an element. But I don´t know how to access to the properties.

Comment: When do you dispatch the `obtenerId` action? Before that is executed, you will get errors reported since your getter will return `undefined`

Comment: Yes, before the Getter is executed, I get undefined. `obtenerId` Action is executed from another file `<button @click="obtenerId(item.id)">Agregar al Carro</button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns `undefined` if nothing matches the predicate.

Since your `id` state property is initially an empty string and none of the `articulos` elements have an empty string id, you get no matches and thus `obtenerArticuloPorId.nombre` generates an error

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nombre')

You can work around this by making access to the potentially `undefined` object safe using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```html
<div class="popup">
  {{ obtenerArticuloPorId?.nombre }}
</div>
```

This will show an empty value until you commit a valid `id` to your store. Alternately, use conditional rendering to wait until you have a valid object

```html
<div class="popup" v-if="obtenerArticuloPorId">
  {{ obtenerArticuloPorId.nombre }}
</div>
```

[image: Edit sad-knuth-g9q0r]

Comment: But when the Getter is executed, it returns an object,  I can see it on the console and the view. I mean, I am getting a match. But I see the whole object, and I need to pull just one property

Comment: @Inca then you use `obtenerArticuloPorId.nombre` (or `obtenerArticuloPorId?.nombre`) like in my answer. I've linked to a CodeSandbox example if you need to see it working